# Gamma distribution getting predictions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Random variable $X$ has a continuous distribution with the probability density function below

$$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{81}{8}x^4e^{-3x}& x > 0 \\
      0 & otherwise \\
\end{cases}
$$

(a) Determine the prediction of for a future $X$, if we have decided to predict using the mean of the distribution

(b) Determine the prediction of a future $X$, if we have decided to predict using the mode of the distribution

(c) Calculate the mean-squared error of the predictor in part(b) above.

---

attempt

I know this is the gamma distribution

(a)

This is $X$ ~ $Gamma(a=5, \lambda=3)$ so $E(X) = \frac{5}{3}$. By definition of Gamma $E(X) = \frac{a}{\lambda}$

(b) $f(x) = \frac{81}{8}x^4e^{-3x}dx$

$f'(x) = \frac{81}{8}x^3e^{-3x}(4-3x) = 0$, so $x = 0, 4/3$

The maximum is given by $x = 4/3$ in the original equation.

$f(4/3) \approx 0.586$

(c)

$MSE(mode) = E(X - \frac{4}{3})^2 = E(X^2 - \frac{8}{3}X + 16/9)$

$E(X^2) - 8/3E(X) + 16/9$

Need to find $E(X^2)$. We know $V(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 \leftrightarrow E(X^2) = V(X) + E(X)^2$ and $V(X) = \frac{a}{\lambda^2} = \frac{5}{9}$ for gamma and $E(X) = \frac{5}{3}$

so $E(X^2) = 5/9 + (5/3)^2 = 10/3$

therefore $MSE(Mode) = E(X^2) - 8/3E(X) + 16/9 = 10/3 - 8/3 \cdot 5/3 + 16/9 = 2/3$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) You are correct to recognize that $X \sim \text{Gamma}(5, 3)$, and your expectation is also correct.

(b) Your mode is correct. A quicker way to do it, however, is to recognize that the mode of random variable following a Gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ is given by $(\alpha - 1)/\lambda$ for $\alpha \geq 1$. So, in this case, the mode would be at $(5 - 1)/3 = 4/3$, which agrees with what you have.

(c) Yes, it is correct.